# How do I assign custom classes to YUI3 plugin/widget objects

Tags: javascript, css, yui3

Consider the following code.

```
var overlay = new Y.Overlay({
                    id:'tooltip-tag',
                    bodyContent:"Loading.....",
                    xy:[e.target.getX(),e.target.getY()+30]
                });
```

The overlay gets the id as given in attributes. But what if I want to add a class ?

IS there something like:

```
var overlay = new Y.Overlay({
                    **class:'tooltip-tag'**,
                    bodyContent:"Loading.....",
                    xy:[e.target.getX(),e.target.getY()+30]
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

No.  Here are three ways to do what you want:

1. Add the class in your markup.  I'm
   guessing this isn't what you want.
2. Subclass Overlay and add a
   `className` config attribute.  If
   you have other customization to do,
   this is an attractive option.
3. Hook the `overlay:render` event and
   attach the class there.  Here's a
   jsfiddle that demonstrates this
   technique:
   http://jsfiddle.net/4zN5M/1/